# Sendmail - asking for recipient is always 5 sec

Tags: caching, delay, centos7, sendmail

Dears,
I have instance of MTA to send MMS via SMTP protocol.I am trying to copy it to new hardware but I have problem with performance. My problem is that sendmail works slowly because asking for Recipient is always 5 sec. In tcpdump we see:

```
 11 2018-12-03 19:42:48.940932852 126.198.210.84 -> 126.198.210.44 SMTP 110 C: RCPT TO:<xxx/TYPE=PLMN@xxx>
 12 2018-12-03 19:42:48.980164242 126.198.210.44 -> 126.198.210.84 TCP 54 smtp > 50621 [ACK] Seq=201 Ack=144 Win=29312 Len=0
 13 2018-12-03 19:42:53.942999601 126.198.210.44 -> 126.198.210.84 SMTP 128 S: 250 2.1.5 <xxx/TYPE=PLMN@xxx>... Recipient ok
```

My domain "xxx" is added to /etc/hosts and in /etc/mail/mailertable. I found that when I clean my cache via:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

Asking for recipient is immediate:

```
12 2018-12-03 19:05:01.617559708 126.198.210.84 -> 126.198.210.44 SMTP 110 C: RCPT TO:<xxx/TYPE=PLMN@xxx>
13 2018-12-03 19:05:01.617569116 126.198.210.44 -> 126.198.210.84 TCP 54 smtp > 41914 [ACK] Seq=201 Ack=144 Win=29312 Len=0
14 2018-12-03 19:05:01.631324501 126.198.210.44 -> 126.198.210.84 SMTP 128 S: 250 2.1.5 <xxx/TYPE=PLMN@xxx>... Recipient ok.
```

Operation system is

```
CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)
```

On old instance I don't have this problem. Configuration of sendmail is the same on both hosts. On old instance I have

```
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.4 (Tikanga)
```

Do you have idea what can be wrong ? 
Regards,
Andrzej

Answer (score 0):

Typical SMTP server does some DNS checks of the recipient.

5s delay **most likely** means that first DNS server/resolver used does not reply.
[It should be confirmed or ruled out first.]

Use `nslookup` or `dig` to ask DNS queries about existing random names and check the reply times.

On Unix/Linux check you `/etc/resolv.conf` for DNS server used as resolvers.

Answer (score 0):

My /etc/resolv.conf is empty on both hosts.
 When I execute nslookup I have:
On new host:

```
# nslookup xxx
;; connection timed out; trying next origin
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

On old host:

```
# nslookup xxx
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

I checked also /etc/nsswitch.conf file on both hosts but they are the same.